# Grunt localhost:9000/index.html doesn't run

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-contrib-connect

I've set it up like Grunt says and I have the following code, grunt is watching correctly and the livereload.js is running on port 35729.

My issue is that I can't see my index.html running on the localhost.
What am I missing?

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({ 
        compass: {
            dev: {
                options: {
                    config: 'config.rb'
                }
            }
        }, 
        watch: {
            css: {
            files: 'sass/*.scss',
            tasks: ['sass'],
            options: { livereload: true }
          },
          livereload: {
            options: { livereload: true },
            files: [
                '{,*/}*.html',
                '*.html',
                'assets/images/{,*/}*',
                'assets/js/*.js'
            ]
        },
        options: {
            livereload: true,
        },

            html: {
                options: { livereload: true },
                files: ['*.html']
            },
            sass: {
                options: { livereload: true },
                files: ['sass/*.scss'],
                tasks: ['compass:dev']
            },
            options: {
              livereload: true
            },
            js: {
                options: { livereload: true },
              files: ['assets/js/*.js'],
              tasks: ['jshint']
            },
            images: {
                options: { livereload: true },
                files: ['assets/images/*.*']
            },
            fontsicons: {
                options: { livereload: true },
                files: ['assets/images/icons/**/*.{svg,eot,woff,ttf,woff2,otf}'],
                tasks: ['copy:fontsicons']
            }
        }, 
        connect: {
            connect: {
                options: {
                    port: 9000,
                    livereload: 35729,
                    hostname: 'localhost'
                },
                livereload: {
                    options: {
                        open: true,
                        base: [
                            'app'
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }); 
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch','compass','connect']);
} //exports
```

Comment: Did you try port:9000?

Comment: @RobertMoskal my locahost is localhost:9000/index.html

Answer (score 1):

By default the grunt-contrib-connect server runs only as long as the grunt module is running: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect#keepalive.

Add the keepalive key to your options:

```
   connect: {
        connect: {
            options: {
                port: 9000,
                livereload: 35729,
                keepalive: true,
                hostname: 'localhost'
            },
```

Keep in mind that no other tasks will run after this one, when you use keepalive.  But from your gruntfile that looks fine.

Comment: thanks for looking into this, still gives me "This webpage is not available" 
not sure why, looks doesn't see or find my index.html